# How to open Master View from Detail View in a master-detail application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, master-detail

I am working on a master-detail iPad application in xcode.

I have a button and textbox in my detail view. When the user clicks on the `button`, it calls a method from the `MasterDetailViewController`

```
- (IBAction)refreshButtonClicked:(id)sender {
[self.parent searchRSSWithURL:self.textBoxOutlet.text];
}
```

(`self.parent` is the `MasterDetailViewController`.) This method creates an array that is used to populate the table view in the `MasterDetailViewController`, and it is doing so successfully.

What I would like to do is also automatically open the Master View when the button is clicked so that the `tableview` can be seen, and I'm not sure how to approach that.

Comment: Are you using `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UINavigationController` then

```
- (IBAction)refreshButtonClicked:(id)sender 
  {
    [self.parent searchRSSWithURL:self.textBoxOutlet.text];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```

Other wise

```
- (IBAction)refreshButtonClicked:(id)sender 
  {
     [self.parent searchRSSWithURL:self.textBoxOutlet.text];
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // OR [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

Comment: should I be using UINavigationController?

Comment: How you are going to master to detail VC ?

Comment: I'm still working on the program, but the idea is that the user will tap on a row in the table view which will take them back to the VC. Do I need `UINavigationController` to do that?

Comment: sorry i can not get u.